# Combinatorics the Rota way, problem 1.1.4; Show ''implies'' generates $\hat{1}$, $\wedge$ (meet) and $\vee$

Tags: combinatorics, logic, boolean-algebra

I'm just starting out a study of combinatorics using the Rota's text: [Combinatorics: The Rota Way](https://books.google.it/books?id=nX5Exky4iGQC&pg=PA1).

I'm confused about what I'm being asked to do here. We are given some binary operation ''implies'' which is defined:

$$x \implies y= x^c \vee y$$

The question is to use this map and $\hat{0}$ (which to my vague knowledge is a ''minimum'' in some sense) to generate the operations $\vee,\wedge$ and the element $\hat{1}$. Then I'm to give a set of axioms using $\implies$ and $\hat{0}$.

Ok so the only thing that makes sense to write is:

$$\hat{0} \implies {\hat{0}}=\hat{0}^c \vee \hat{0} = \hat{1}$$
(please confirm). So I have $\hat{1}$ but now how do I generate the other operations?

Edit; Thanks to comments I now see how to construct $\wedge$, $\vee$, $^c$. I'm still struggling with ''give a set of axioms using $\implies$ & $\hat{0}$. Am I supposed to just go through all the Lattice axioms, distribivity, etc and translate them?  For example I tried to recreate idempotency by;

$$(x \implies 0) \implies x =x \implies (x \implies 0) \implies 0=x $$

Is this the right approach?

Comment: See [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Operations): we define e.g. $x^c := x \to 0$ and $x \land y := (x \to y^c)^c$

Comment: $x \lor y$ as been defined as $x^c  \to y$ and finally $1=0^c=0 \to 0$

Comment: Yes; you can start from a "narrowed" set of [axioms for BA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbins_algebra) and replace $\lor$ and $\lnot$ with their definition in terms of $\to$ and $0$.

Comment: What is ROTA? If it's a reference that is relevant to your question, you should give a proper reference in the body of your question.

Comment: There seems to be a book titled "Combinatorics the Rota Way" by Kung, Rota & Yan.